# Altering foreach variable for specific object in controls (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform (VisualStudio 2013, C#) with several types of objects. I want to change property (visibility) in all objects of one type. Here is my formulation:

```
private void offToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;
    foreach (Control g in Controls)
    {
        GroupBox v = (GroupBox)g;
        g.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Problem is, Visual Studio sends me this message when I want to start my form:

> Error 1: A local variable named 'v' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'v', which is already
>   used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else  E:\3D Tic
>   Tac Toe - druhá verze\3D Tic Tac Toe - druhá verze\Form1.cs   2203    26  3D
>   Tic Tac Toe - druhá verze

No matter what message says, I do not use variable v anywhere else in the program. I am probably looking for some kind of exception handler or so.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: take a look at this `GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;` and this `GroupBox v = (GroupBox)g;`

Answer (score 1):

You defined `v` twice within the current scope:

```
**GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;**
foreach (Control g in Controls)
{
    **GroupBox v = (GroupBox)g;**
    g.Visible = false;
}
```

It looks like you're trying to hide all controls *within* the groupbox? If this is the case I would modify your code to something like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

Or if you need to hide all `GroupBox` types:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
        ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

Or to hide all controls on the form:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable `v` outside of your loop: `GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;`

So in the loop you can't use `v` variable name again as it is already present in the current scope.

But note: actually you don't need this line `GroupBox v = (GroupBox)g;` in loop at all since you're not using `v` variable in your loop.

UPDATE.

From this part of your question: *I am probably looking for some kind of exception handler or so.* - it is not very clear what you're asking. You don't need any exception handler to handle this kind of errors since it is *compile time* error, not *run-time* one.

Answer (score 0):

```
-> GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;
foreach (Control g in Controls)
{
    -> GroupBox v = (GroupBox)g;
    g.Visible = false;
}
```

You might also want to change your loop to this:

```
foreach (GroupBox g in Controls)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused with your question, as your code will most likely produce other errors.

I think the solution you might be looking for should look like this:

```
private void offToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox v = (GroupBox)sender;

    foreach (Control g in Controls)
    {
        if (g is GroupBox) // only if g is a GroupBox set Visible to false
            g.Visible = false;
    }
}
```